# problem installing texlive 2014 on ubuntu

Tags: installing, texlive

I have tried to remove and install texlive on my PC with Ubuntu 14 (64 bit). But the version that is installed is 2013. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: You are going to need to give us more details. For example, are we talking about the version of TeX Live from the Ubuntu Package Manager or one downloaded from TUG? If the latter, exactly what did you download, ...

Comment: I downloaded the install script from here: [https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). I then ran the scrip as instructed.

Comment: OK, how are you determining the TeX Live version: I presume something like `pdftex --version`? What does `which pdftex` give? Did you add the 'vanilla' TeX Live to your path?

Comment: I ran `tex --version`. But I get the same result with `pdftex --version`. The path given by `which pdftex` is `/usr/bin/pdftex`

Comment: However, texlive is in `usr/local/texlive/2014`

Comment: in my (similar) situation, i amend my `$PATH` by `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014:$PATH`

Comment: I tried with `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014:$PATH`. It did not work. Using `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` did change the path. But when I log out it returns to the old path. And even before I log out, when trying to update texlive I still get the error `(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
  (2014--2014)
do not include the version of the local installation
  (2013).
`

Comment: I think you've got the same issue I had [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148072/28808).  The good answer is to uninstall the lot, especially anything ubuntu installed, and start again.  The bad answer is a permanent change to your PATH (this is what I did): in `~/.profile` I added the line: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` at the end (in your case it will be 2014, don't know about any other changes).

Comment: My tex vesion now shows as *texlive 2014*. However, when i try to update packages I get this error `http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
  (2014--2014)
do not include the version of the local installation
  (2013).
`

Comment: Here is a recent [question related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196451/packages-to-install-once-for-all/196466#196466) where also cites another three that helped me to install correctly TeXLive 2013 and 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04.