# texdoc package-name results no documentation found

Tags: texdoc

`texdoc package-name` provided package's manual in previous in my system.
But, now it results -

```
    $ texdoc beamer
    Sorry, no documentation found for beamer.  
    If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
    http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and my LaTeX-2016. I have installed it from tug.org.
A few days ago I noticed that when I updated my ubuntu packages from ubuntu software updater there was `latex-base`. I have installed all those updates. I don't know whether the problem occurs for those updates or not.

**Edit 1**
provided that `tlmgr update --self` results -

```
$ tlmgr update --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).
```

and `which texdoc` results -
`/usr/bin/texdoc`

I will be highly glad if you provide any fruitful solution.

Comment: Now you have two LaTeX installations. So you probably need to figure out which LaTeX installation your texdoc refers to (try `which texdoc`). You should not need to run texdoc under sudo

Comment: like @daleif said, you might be using two LaTeX distributions. you could try to uninstall the one you got from the ubuntu repo (might need synaptic pkg mgr) and install the newest version (should be TL 2017) you find on tug.org. I had a similar problem a while ago, but I really don't remember all I had to do to solve it. basically, I tried checking paths and dependencies, updating TL 2016 to 2017 and other things. I'm pretty sure I ended up reinstalling a fresh version from tug.org/texlive. you could try `tlgmgr update --self` and see what that does for you.

Comment: Especially the fact that you are using `sudo texdoc...` may cause it to use the Ubuntu installed LaTeX instead of the TUG one. For example did you prepend the TUG PATH to the path root uses?

Comment: I wrote `sudo` by mistake. It is not working without `sudo`. I edited my question.

Comment: @thymaro I think it should be `tlmgr update --self` instead of `tlgmgr update --self`

Comment: @thymaro it results - `$ tlmgr update --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).
`

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal What does ` which texdoc` say? (t repeat daleif's comment)

Comment: @samcarter `which texdoc` results `/usr/bin/texdoc`

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Seems to be the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148072/force-use-of-tex-live-in-usr-local-instead-of-old-copy-in-usr-bin?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Either uninstall the distribution installed by your package manager or put your self installed distribution (probably in `/usr/local/texlive/...`) at the start of your path variable in order to get the `texdoc` from there.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150892/multiple-texlive-installations may also help

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Don't overwrite your complete path, just add it in front. Try `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH"`

Comment: Since you say you want to remove Ubuntu's packages and install just upstream TL, please consult https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=6|1.1949 which explains the process in detail. It will go best if you take the time to digest the instructions there so that you know why things are being done - even if you decide to use one of the scripts to automate all or part of the process.

Comment: You know what the problem is and what the options are. Have you now got this sorted? Did you try @samcarter's suggestion, for example? You said before you wanted to remove Ubuntu's installation. Have you read the information in the thread I linked to?

Comment: @cfr I tried samcarter's solution. It works.